# Can the toast show again when I have canceled it

Tags: android

I have run this method

```
sToast.cancel();
```

can I call this method

```
sToast.show();
```

I have tried it.the sToast can show in GB, but not in ICS.
Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, calling show() after cancel() doesn't show any Toast on screen. Do check properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Toast.cancel()`. Usually a Toast cancels by itself after a timeout so usually programmers never end up using cancel. If there is a need, you can very well go ahead and use it.